# SQLAlchemy double-quoting LIKE filter

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

For some reason, SQLAlchemy is double-quoting the LIKE filter value of my queries!

The code is this:

```
query = app.db.session.query(model.Attribute)\   
  .filter(model.Attribute.name == 'photo0')\
  .filter(model.Attribute.value.like('%' + file + '%'))\
  .all()
```

Pretty simple and straight forward. It should produce something like `value LIKE '%78744154439.htm%'` but SQLAlchemy is adding additional double-quotes.

Here's the DB echo from this query:

```
2014-07-17 14:32:24,472 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT attributes.listing_id AS attributes_listing_id, attributes.id AS attributes_id, attributes.name AS attributes_name, attributes.value AS attributes_value 
FROM attributes 
WHERE attributes.name = %s AND attributes.value LIKE %s
2014-07-17 14:32:24,472 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('photo0', '"%78744154439.htm%"')
```

I've tried to escape the % thinking it was due to string escaping, but still nothing!

I'm running Python 2.7.6 with SQLAlchemy 0.9.6 and MySQL-python 1.2.5 as my DBAPI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get around this by using the following syntax:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

query = app.db.session.query(model.Attribute)\      
       .filter(model.Attribute.name == 'photo0')\   
       .filter(model.Attribute.value.like(text("'%" + file + "%'"))\   
       .all()
```

HTH

Comment: This is open to SQL injection.